# Protect API for Mobile app behind Authentication

Tags: firebase, api, react-native, authentication

I am building a react native mobile application, and I'm using the expo Google and Apple sign in libraries to provide authentication. Both libraries use firebase to authenticate, but my database is hosted elsewhere (heroku while in development, but probably migrating to digital ocean in the future). How can I protect my API using the access tokens I receive from the Google and Apple sign in utilities on my non-firebase server? All the code samples I've seen use firebase as the backend. I want to make sure that all the API calls are authenticated, and that the proper storing/refreshing techniques are used on the client, while maintaining the "persistent session" UX for users so they don't have to sign in every time they open the application.

I feel like I should know this, and I have a few ideas, but really don't want to get this aspect of the application wrong.

Comment: The code to interact with firebase-admin to [check the validity of a Firebase Auth ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) should be basically the same no matter what your backend is.

Comment: Maybe you can save the token retrieved from firebase in your database and check for other API calls that contain this token or not (protected API call )